# High-side driver currentsense k factor

Tags: current-measurement, driver

The [VN7004CLH](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group0/8c/07/88/63/10/a6/43/91/DM00177922/files/DM00177922.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00177922.pdf) High-side driver with CurrentSense has a pin (CS) that allows one to measure the output current via a microcontroller ADC or similar.

The current can be calculated using the following formula

[image]

Notice the need for a k factor.  The k factor is defined in the datasheet as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can calculate the k factor?
Does each driver need to be calibrated against a reference and the k factor calculated from that result, (that would not be good).

Comment: ??? Did you read the whole datasheet? Table 10? Figures 4 and 5?

Comment: @AliChen I missed that, thanks.  However, the problem remains as the range is so broad for k factor e.g. K0 IOUT/ISENSE IOUT = 1 A; VSENSE = 0.5 V 9000 16650 24500

Comment: @AliChen k factor is between 9000 & 24500, not really that helpful... a bit like Earth is between Mars and Venus.

Comment: Yes, this IC doesn't look particularly accurate with regard to measuring the current. You probably need to choose some other IC for this function, or to incorporate some individual calibration routine on each sample of your product. You didn't mention how accurately you want to measure the current.